# Limit the number of letter returned from a DB recordset field

Tags: php, vb.net

I have to following string ASP VB string:

```
<%= Left ((rsMyRecordset.Fields.Item("text").Value), 75)%>
```

This returns 75 characturers only from the left

How do I do the same thing in PHP, my current string is:

```
<?php echo $row_rsMyRecordset['text']; ?>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up `substr` in the php manual

Comment: substr seem to be a way or returning certain letters within a string not simply outputting a given number of letters.

Comment: Correct, so `substr($string, 0, 75)` will return the first 75 characters